# How do i right align an icon set arrow under conditional formatting so that both number and arrow are on right side of cell neatly together?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

Cell displays a conditional format arrow Icon set which is on far left side of cell. The number in that cell is right aligned and I want to bring the arrow directly next to the number. I want the arrow to be closer to the number in the cell as i have other cells with arrows and it is confusing which arrow belongs to which box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to move the icon set. However, you can achieve a visual effect that will help eliminate confusion with multiple columns displaying icons.

Highlight the column which you wish to bring the numbers and icon closer together.

Right Click.

Select Format Cells.

Click the Alignment tab if it does not appear by default.

Locate the Horizontal Text Alignment drop down box.

Select Right (Indent)

Change the Indent value to one that moves your numbers to a position that visually eliminates the confusion.

Click OK.

Check the results and adjust the Indent value as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You can align the icon if when you setup the formula check the box "Show Icon only".

With the icon only showing, the Centering of the content of the cell will apply to the Icon.

[image: Icon centered in cell]